# How to conditionally pass parameters in Java to a method that takes a variable number of arguments?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, parameter-passing

I'm using the JDO Query class and I need to conditionally pass certain parameters to the `execute` method, as demonstrated in the code below.

I don't know how to do this in Java.

```
query.declareParameters("String alphaP");
query.declareParameters("String bravoP");
query.declareParameters("String charlieP");

if (condition) {
    if (othercondition) {
        query.declareParameters("List<String> stringList");
    }
    else {
        query.declareParameters("String simpleString");
    }
}

if (someothercondition) {
    query.declareParameters("int deltaP");
}

if (yetanothercondition) {
    query.declareParameters("int echoP");
}

if (thelastcondition) {
    query.declareParameters("int foxtrotP");
}

List<ResultClass> results = (List<ResultClass>) query.execute(
    alphaP, 
    bravoP, 
    charlieP,

    // ... and whatever other parameters are required based on 
    // which conditions are true above

    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`executeWithArray`](http://tjdo.sourceforge.net/docs/api/jdo/javax/jdo/Query.html#executeWithArray(java.lang.Object[])) method: dynamically build up the array of parameters using an instance of `java.util.ArrayList` which you can then convert to an array using the `toArray` method. The code might look something like the following:

```
ArrayList<Object> args = new ArrayList<Object>();
args.add(alphaP);
args.add(bravoP);
args.add(charlieP);
// Add other arguments here...

List<ResultClass> results = (List<ResultClass>) query.executeWithArray(args.toArray());
```

Comment: +1  if everybody checked API before asking questions, we'd have no reputation here. Also, executeWithMap might be a bit simpler.

Answer (score 6):

> How to conditionally pass parameters in Java to a method that takes a variable number of arguments?

@Richard has answered the specific question with regards to the JDO `Query` class.  (Use one of the alternative `queryWith...` methods.)

The answer to the more general question is that "it depends".  Specifically, it depends on the method signatures.

1) If the method is declared to take a
   variable number of parameters passed
   as an array, list, map or whatever,
   then the answer is obvious.  Assemble
   the actual parameters in an array /
   list / map / whatever, and pass them.

2) If the method is declared with a
   "varargs" parameter, then you can
   pass an explicit array of actual
   parameters; e.g.

```
  public void test(String... args) { ... }

  test("Hi", "Mom");
  test(new String[]{"Hi", "Pa"});
  String[] args = new String[]{"Hi", "Bro"};
  test(args);
```

3) If there are actually multiple
   overloaded methods, then you have no
   choice but to programmaticaly select
   and call the appropriate overload
   based on the number of parameters you
   have to pass:

```
  public void test(String arg1) { ... }
  public void test(String arg1, String arg2) { ... }
  ...

  if (nosArgs == 1) {
      test(arg1);
  } else if (nosArgs == 2) {
      test(arg1, arg2);
  } else ...
```

You might think that reflection would help, because when you call a method reflectively you pass the actual arguments as an `Object[]`.  But this doesn't help much because you also need to use the appropriate `Method` object, and each of the overloads of (say) the `test` method has a different `Method` object.  So you end up with conditional / switch code that is equivalent to the non-reflective case.